# Webix Pager scroll to particular row

Tags: webix

The datatable has a select method, which selects a given row.
The pager also has a select method, which scrolls to a given page.

However, I cannot find a way to tell the pager to scroll to a page which contains a given row.

Namely, I want to select a row in the datatable, but also show it if the view is on a different page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific method that can both select and show the needed row at a time, but the combination of the following methods will do the job well:

```
datatable.select(35); //selects row
datatable.showItem(35); //scrolls or pages to make the row visible
```

Comment: Well, that's quite enough. I will test it tomorrow and then mark your answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See at this example in the [Snippets](http://webix.com/snippet/5aafae67)

```
    webix.ui({
rows:
[
  { view:"button", type:"iconButton",icon:"fa fa-bolt",label:"Go 52", width:100,on:
    {
     'onItemClick': function()
       {
         $$("dTable").select(52);
     $$("dTable").showItem(52);
       } 
    }
  },
  {
      view:"datatable",name:"dTable",id:"dTable",select:true,
      columns:[
        { id:"rank",  header:"", css:"rank",      width:50},
        { id:"title", header:"Film title",width:200},
        { id:"year",  header:"Released" , width:80},
        { id:"votes", header:"Votes",   width:100}
      ],
      autowidth:true,
      data: big_film_set    
  },

]
});
```

big_film_set it is a variable with a JSON.

```
var big_film_set = [{"id":1,"title":"The Shawshank Redemption","year":"1994","votes":"678.79","rating":"9.2","rank":"1"} /*...*/ ];
```